# What is the best way to transfer my files to Azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, disk, azcopy

What is the best way to transfer my files to the `Azure` virtual machine? I tried below options, but no luck

**Option 1: AzCopy**

I am ware of `AzCopy` which helps to copy the files to a storage account, However, my requirement is to copy the file from my local machine (on-premise network share) to cloud Azure `Virtual Machine` disk.My Virtual Machine's are using managed disks. Hence I do not think I can use `AzCopy`

**Option 2: Azure File Share**

I also thought of using `File Share` option, but I am sure if it's right choice.

Basically I want to automate the copy process to target VM's.

Advice appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Network Drive, this is the easiest and the best way. If you just need to share between two VM's and don't have any additional interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to create a ***file share*** between two machines.

**First**, you need to Allow Inbound connection to your Azure VM from on-premises. Perhaps this is could be the case in your way, please go through this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/298804/internet-firewalls-can-prevent-browsing-and-file-sharing), for enabling correct port if you don't want to expose everything.

**Second**, you should create a [network drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026635/windows-10-map-a-network-drive).

**Last**, create a scheduler task with [XCopy](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-automate-copy-of-files-from-one-folder-to/3f1c05ca-e89d-4f5f-9290-b1368531d1c0) or [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7).

You can even create a [Hybrid Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-windows-hrw-install) in Automation Account for running your job from the Cloud to on-premises.

Comment: But how do I copy to file share folder? Each file size is near to 1gb, and manual copy paste takes ages.

Comment: Copy-Item 'D:\temp\Test Folder' -Destination 'F:\temp\Test Folder1'

Comment: Copy speed only depends from your Internet bandwidth

Comment: Sounds good.  So there is no way to copy from storage account to VM disk? I am thinking of using azcopy as first step to copy to storage account

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `Azure File Sync` is what you are after. It's a service that allows you to install agents on a VM that'll take care of syncing up with an Azure File Share. The following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/storage/files/storage-sync-files-deployment-guide) gives a good overview on how to set it up and its capabilities.

Comment: link is to dutch version, english one is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-sync-files-deployment-guide?tabs=azure-portal%2Cproactive-portal

Comment: FYI...seems to be a service for Windows VMs only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure File share to map a permanent drive into your local machine.
You will need to make sure that SMB port isn't blocked within your firewall.

You can use the following Azure powershell command:

New-PSDrive -Name "S" -Root "<Your_StorageAccountName>.file.core.windows.net/" -Persist -PSProvider "Registry"

Answer (score 0):

The best way to transfer files on Vm is using google drive:

1. upload your files on google drive
2. Get id from shareable Link
3. login to your VM
4. finally run this command

   wget --no-check-certificate 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=this_is_the_id_of_files_on_drive' -O new_Name_any.rar

Thats it